# read_train_sets() missing 1 required positional argument: 'classes'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been looking over a few Tensorflow and Keras guides and am generally as much of a beginner as you can get when it comes to Python. Any help with the below problem would be much appreciated. I'm struggling to figure out what the problem with this line of code below is. I'm getting the read_train_sets from a separate file that is defined as:

`def read_train_sets(self, train_path, image_width, image_height, classes, validation_size)`

I then called this in a separate file with the following code:

`data = read_train_sets(train_path, img_width, img_height, classes, validation_size=0.2)`

But then I got an error message that says:

```
<ipython-input-22-e2aa446e36dd> in <module>
----> 1 data = read_train_sets(train_path, img_width, img_height, classes, validation_size=0.2)

TypeError: read_train_sets() missing 1 required positional argument: 'classes'
```

Any idea what this means? I thought I'm already calling classes, but then again, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `read_train_set` is a function that belongs to the class `DataSet`.

In your code:

```
data = read_train_sets(train_path, img_width, img_height, classes, validation_size=0.2)
```

You are using this function as you created it yourself, and the error tells you that you are lacking one argument because it does not identify the `self` argument when you call the function.

The correct way to call that function should be something like:

```
data = dataset.read_train_sets(train_path, img_width, img_height, classes, validation_size=0.2)
```

You will need to previously create a `DataSet` object (I named it *dataset* in the example).

Source: https://github.com/rdcolema/tensorflow-image-classification/blob/master/dataset.py